# Using a local variable as part of a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use the contents of a string variable to check if a record exists in a database.  I am sending a method 2 parameters.  This is the receiving method:

```
public Boolean recordExists(String targetTable, String data)
{
   //a bunch of Table connections strings are here, example:
   Table<Road> Roads = db.GetTable<Road>();

   //check if the record exists in the table (an integer in this case)
   var roadQuery = from id in targetTable where id.ID == Convert.ToInt32(data) select id;
}
```

For example, the value of 'targetTable' could be "Roads", and I would want to see if the value 'data' exists in the ID field of the Roads table in the database.  How would I create a dynamic LINQ query to do this?

Comment: Do you mean "manually via Expression", or "with the dynamic LINQ sample", or ... ?

Comment: Frankly, LINQ isn't really *intended* to support usage such as `string targetTable` (although it would perhaps work for `<TEntity>` (generics). Can you be clearer about the scenario?

Comment: The user will enter an integer into a textbox in a form.  I would like to then check the database to see if that number exists in the ID field of a certain table.  The table depends upon which textbox a number is entered into (therefore the target table varies).

Answer (score 2):

It's simple brother :

```
public bool recordExists(String targetTable, string fieldName, String data)
        {
            return (bool)(db.ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [{0}] WHERE [{1}] = '{2}'",
                targetTable, fieldName, data).Single() > 0);
        }
```

**Note** : single quote work in SQL even Field is numeric.

Comment: It looks like that may work for now.  I was hoping to keep my queries strictly in LINQ though.

Comment: @Nords if you want to keep you query strictly LINQ, then you can't start from `string targetTable`; that is not amenable to LINQ.

Comment: @Amen you probably need a `.First()` / `.Single()` etc on the end of that?

Comment: +1, @MarcGravell, you mean SingleOrDefault() != null, so we dont get an exception, plus i dont know if Nords want to return false if more than record exists

Comment: The records will be unique, as the fields are mostly primary keys.

Comment: @Amen `COUNT` here will always return a row, even if the answer is `0`. No real need for `OrDefault`. Also, `<bool>` will never return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public bool recordExists(String targetTable, string fieldName, String data)
{
        return db.ExecuteQuery<bool>(string.Format(@"SELECT 
                                CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM [{0}] WHERE [{1}]='{2}') 
                                    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
                                    ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
                                END",targetTable,fieldName,data));
}
```